# JPA, Standalone application and entity manager

Tags: java, jpa

I'm developing an application that should run in my pc and that should do some operations after it retrieve some data in a mysql database.
I created entity classes and jpa controller classes using the wizards on Netbeans 8.0.2 and now I would use these classes in a Main.java to retrieve a single object.
Why do I receive a `NullPointerException` on `EntityManager`/`EntityManagerFactory`?
The original file starts like:

```
public class TestJpaController implements Serializable {

    public TestJpaController(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

The problems was how  I could pass the `EntityManagerFactory` and I found somewhere that with `@PersistenceContext` I should resolve so I modify the code:

```
public class TestJpaController implements Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestPU")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em ;
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Where is my error?

I'm using: JDK 1.7, JPA 2.1 and, as I already wrote, Netbeans 8.0.2

The lines of code in Main.java are:

```
TestController tc= new TestController();
Test t= tc.findTest(1);
```

where 1 is an ID that I know that exists!
The method `findTest()`, created automatically by wizard, is:

```
public Test findTest(Integer id) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        return em.find(Ordine.class, id);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

and, after the @Shashi 's answer, the problem is on `em.close();`!

I'm reading this article:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/persistenceapi-135534.html
and I would add some lines of my persistence.xml:

  
    org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    Test

I forgot another little thing ... I found the properties that recreate the db schema into the persistence.xml but, for my luck, it didn't happen!
Can it be useful?

Comment: could you attach your Main method code?

Comment: You don't create the factory anywhere. For the annotation to workt, you need a framework that will inject the instance.

Comment: @f1sh : did you mean the file persistence.xml? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with my original files!
The problem, I suppose, was into jar imported: originally I added Glassfish's files to manage persistence's dependencies; now I download the last version of eclipse link and I import these files!

Answer (score 1):

Call the class ConnectionInstanceManager  for **EntityManagerFactory**. Hope this will work

```
public class ConnectionInstanceManager {

private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;
private static EntityManager entityManager = null;
private static EntityTransaction entityTransaction = null;


public ConnectionInstanceManager() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public static void createConnectionInstance(){

    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpaservices");
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

}
public static void destroyConnectionInstance(ConnectionInstanceManager connectionInstanceManager){
    ConnectionInstanceManager.entityManagerFactory= null;
    ConnectionInstanceManager.entityManager= null;
    ConnectionInstanceManager.entityTransaction = null;
}
public ConnectionInstanceManager getConnectionInstance(){
    createConnectionInstance();
    return ConnectionInstanceManager.this;

}
public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
    return entityManagerFactory;
}
public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    return entityManager;
}
public EntityTransaction getEntityTransaction(){
    return entityTransaction;
}

public ConnectionInstanceManager getConnectionInstanceforfetch(){
    fetchConnectionInstance();
    return ConnectionInstanceManager.this;

}
public static void fetchConnectionInstance(){

    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpaservices");
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();


}
```

}

Comment: I created the new class and now the problem is when I close EntityManager object into the method of TestController.java! I modify only a thing on your file     entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpaservices"); to     entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestPU");

Comment: did you mean the name of persistence unit with jpaservice?

Comment: yes, the persistence unit will be jpaservice, coz we are assigning the same to createEntityManagerFactory. as jpaservice. In your case it might be mismatched....Please check that